# Drop in Numbers while comparing Real-time vs Behavior reports - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are tracking form registrations and the count of users who registered using the form that is put up in our website.

So we did a bit of testing, and when we registered 10 users within 30 minutes, under Realtime -> Behavior it showed me the exact number as 10 users.
Whereas when I pulled the report from Behaviour -> Site Content -> All Pages, I see that there is a significant drop (showed me the number as only 6 people registered).

The users are redirected to a 'thank you/successful registered' page after the registration is a success. In this case, I view the count of the thank you pages under real-time in order to see how many have registered.

Could someone please help me out here. Why is there a drop in number between the real-time and behaviour report?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you wait at least some considerable amount of time before checking the report ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I waited for around 24 hours and still the numbers weren't matching. If I make 10 registrations, only 7 show.